# Why does Captain Jack Sparrow return to the Black Pearl when attacked by the Kraken?

Tags: pirates-of-the-caribbean, dead-mans-chest

In ***Pirates of the Caribbean: Dead Man's Chest***, at the end when the Kraken attacks the Black Pearl, Captain Jack Sparrow tries to run away in a small boat. Then he comes back, shoots the barrel, Elizabeth ties him and then he enteres into the Kraken's mouth.

My question is why does he come back?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Change of heart :-)

Comment: The Kraken doesn't chew? ;)

Comment: I think pirates believed that a ship to be properly be sunken, it's captain should get sunken along. There's a dialog between Jack and Barbossa in the fourth movie, **Jack Sparrow: Lost the Pearl?
Barbossa: Aye. I defended her mightily enough. But she sunk none the less.
[suddenly Jack goes to grab Barbossa, but the King’s guards grab hold of him]
Jack Sparrow: If that ship be sunk properly, you should be sunk with it.**

Answer (score 14):

Jack was shown checking [his compass](http://pirates.wikia.com/wiki/Jack_Sparrow%27s_compass) to decide whether or not to go back and help. However, what the compass told him was never shown. My understanding is that he came back because the compass pointed towards the *Black Pearl*. He looked at the compass as he was in a moral dilemma because he had abandoned his crew and friends to die when he alone was responsible for their situation.

Answer (score 8):

Jack has two drives:

1. Self-preservation
2. Being captain of a ship

It has been shown time and again how Jack will go to extraordinary lengths to become captain of a ship, even if it's just a rowboat (as seen at the end of At World's End). When the Kraken was attacking The Black Pearl, Jack's first instinct was the same as anyone else's would be in such a position - run. But when he got far enough away from the ship to see the Kraken breaking up his ship, he realized that as captain he should be with his ship and his crew.

The only reason he stayed on the boat after trying to help everyone else get off is because Elizabeth had tied him up. But you'll also notice that even once he gets free, he accepts his fate and actually tries to attack the Kraken before being swallowed. Jack stayed true to his principle - the captain goes down with his ship.

Comment: He always wanted to be captain of the Black Pearl especially. Even he was in this mess, because he made deal with davy jones to raise the ship.

Comment: which ship to raise?

Comment: This ship black pearl, he got it raised from bottom of ship by Davy Jones and that's the debt he owed

Answer (score 0):

The reason why he came back is because he's their Captain, and Captain's NEVER let down his crew, no matter WHAT situation he's in. He came back because he ran away from his own ship the *Black Pearl*. Elizabeth saw Jack rowing a boat and then she said, "coward". Jack then sees that the Kraken had taken over his entire ship and he goes back. Elizabeth chains him with a rope or something and then she left, leaving him to die. Jack, after being "eaten" by the Kraken, was in Davy Jones's locker and then he sees his crew. Elizabeth said, "Jack come with us" or something like that. Jack replies, "Why should I sail with any of you? Four of you have tried to kill me in the past . . . one of you succeeded." Jack looks at Elizabeth and then Will Turner looks at Elizabeth. It was Elizabeth's fault.

Comment: I'm not sure how the latter two thirds of this answer try to adress the question. They just seem to be a mere retelling of the story as seen in the movie.